# can someone explain this modulo problem in python?

Tags: python

what im trying to do is print a message 9 times and separate each three lines with ---------------
example :

```
message
message
message
_______
message
message
message
_______
message
message
message
_______
```

this is my attempt

```
for i in range(9):
    print("message")
    print(i+1,(i+1 % 3) )
    if i+1 % 3 == 0 :
        print("--------------")
```

when i+1 is a multiplier of 3 we sperate to know that its a multiplier i used the modulo  for example if i+1 = 3 then 3 mod 3 should equal to 0 that mean its a multiplayer but it does not equal to 0 in this case so the if statement does not get excuted can some one explain . no alternative solution please just want to understand

each message is in a new line stack overflow formats texts wrongly

Comment: Instead of things get executed or not, can you narrow it down to the condition of the if statement? Can you produce a value for i for which the condition behaves differently from what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is checking if `x + (1%3)==0` which never happens. To correct this, just add parantheses:

```
for i in range(9):
    print("message")
    # print(i+1,(i+1 % 3) )
    if (i+1) % 3 == 0 :
        print("--------------")
```